# Стоит ли переписывать скрипт build.gradle(на уровне проекта) из-за firebase

Tags: firebase, gradle, android-gradle

Мне нужно подключить базу данных Firebase к Java Android проекту в Android Studio. На этапе подключения Firebase к файлу build.gradle(на уровне проекта) я столкнулся с проблемой: структура этого файла полностью не совпадала со структурой официального сайта Firebase.
Файл build.gradle у меня:

```
plugins{
      id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
      id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
}
```

Структура того же файла на официальном сайте Firebase:

```
buildscript{
      repositories{
         //Make sure that you have the following two repositories
         google()
         maveCentral()
      }
      dependencies{
         //Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
      }
}
allprojects{
      repositories{
         //Make sure that you have the following two repositories 
         google()
         maveCentral()
      }
}
```

Как и куда мне следует добавить все эти строки кода?